# Image Rotates when being Compressed in react-native-compressor

Tags: react-native, image

When I upload a portrait image in React native using the following settings:

```
       const result = await COM.compress(image.uri, {
          compressionMethod: 'manual',
          maxWidth: 3000,
          quality: 0.9,
        });
```

It turns into a landscape image as shown below:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIrvP.jpg)  - [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs7xJ.jpg)

I am using the following react library:  react-native-compressor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix the issue, change the following settings from manual to auto as shown below:

```
  const result = await COM.compress(image.uri, {
          compressionMethod: 'manual',
          maxWidth: 3000,
          quality: 0.9,
        });
```

to

```
  const result = await COM.compress(image.uri, {
          compressionMethod: 'auto',

        });
```